# Informatica Connection to OCI ADW during installation

Tags: oracle, informatica, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to install `Informatica 10.1` on `OCI` and thereby connecting it to `ADW` for the `INFA` users access.

I've successfully established connectivity with `ADW` through `sqlplus` using the wallet keys. However, during the `Informatica` installation I'm not able to connect to the `ADW` database. Below is an excerpt of the connection that is being tried by the installer.

```
Configure the database for the domain configuration repository:

Database type:
    * 1->Oracle
      2->SQLServer
      3->DB2
      4->Sybase
(Default: 1):

Database user ID: (default :- dbadmin) :

User password: (default :- ) :

Configure the database connection
      1->JDBC URL
    * 2->Custom JDBC Connection String
(Default: 2):
```

I'm wary on the custom `JDBC` Connection String that is being asked. Usually the default string is something like this:
`jdbc:informatica:oracle://somestringfromtnsnames.oraclecloud.com:1521;ServiceName=somestringfromtnsnames.adb.oraclecloud.com`

But in this case I'm connecting to ADW via wallet & ideally the wallet information should be provided. I just am not sure how. I've prepared a string in accordance to the same which I thought was correct, but it doesn't work.

`jdbc:informatica:oracle:@tnsnamesalias?TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/my/wallet/store`

Has anyone got any idea on this? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the DataDirect JDBC drivers used by Informatica do not support Oracle's encryption, which is required to access ADW. It appears that you can use Oracle Client on an existing Informatica installation to add ADW as a target, but not using JDBC or ODBC. There appear to be limitations to this in terms of metadata access, and some import steps will need to be completed manually.

In spite of what it implies in "[Autonomous Database 3rd Party Tools and Applications](https://www.oracle.com/autonomous-database/tools/)" for [Informatica](https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/informatica96-connection-adw.pdf), the only way to complete a *new* installation - according to the steps in Appendix A of the doc - is to first disable the SQL*Net encryption. This requires a level of access to the Oracle configuration files and processes that does not exist for Autonomous Database services (i.e. access to sqlnet.ora and lsnrctl). It only exists if you are running your own VM host (Infrastructure as a Service) with a stand-alone installation of Oracle Database that you fully control.